# CSS :active should become "inactive" after a specific time

Tags: css, hover

for mobile I used :hover :active to create a transition effect on tab(click) that increases the size of the elements to give more information. I want the activated element to become "inactive" again after a certain time has elapsed. I was unable to find a comparable question.

edit: The problem appears to be that the element is now permanently "hovered", I would like the element to be not hovered after a couple seconds

edit2: http://jsfiddle.net/qw8vyrxd/

```
.box {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
.box:hover, .box:active{
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
}
}
```

on mobile the red square will expand on click ( triggering hover selector ) but will never retract unless page reloaded, I want the hover effect to only last a couple seconds.

Best regards

Comment: What exactly is your problem? As far as I've tested `:active` doesn't least on element after click on touch screen. What is your element (button, link)? Could you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. My code is currently convulted, I will try to extract the relevant parts. For mobile I used .class:hover, .class:active{the hover effects/transitions} to get my "hover" effect on tab {for mobile}. Thinking about it, I think the problem is that the hover effect is now "permanent". So I likely want to stop the element to be "hovered" Best regards

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qw8vyrxd/ . If you click red square on mobile it will expand but it will never retract unless you reload the page. This appears to be the permanent hover effect, so basically how can I deactivate the hover selector after a while

Answer (score 0):

The state that remains on the element on touch screen is `:hover` (in my situation), not `:active`. Touch screen keeps the `:hover` state until you click somewhere else.

So I solved this by applying `:hover` only to the device that supports it (using **media queries hover:hover**) and leaving `:active` without media queries. On touch screen state `:active` is active for as long as the user has their finger on the element.

```css
.box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box:active {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  .box:hover {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

This solved it on my devices. I had to use real devices because DevTools kept acting like mouse even through simulated touch.

---

#### Delayed version

Since pseudo states are difficult to control with JS, I wanted to use only CSS. I used a little walkaround-hack. I set `transition` to 0s and then `transition-delay` by `2s`. Then I overloaded/disabled this for devices that support hover.

It means it appears bigger on touch screen for 2 seconds.

```css
.box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0s height, 0s width;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}

.box:active {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  .box {
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
  .box:hover {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to answer. Is it possible to add a time to that, so that the hover effects lasts for a specific duration?

Comment: @user3740523 I've just added variant with delay but it is a little bit hacky.